# How to pass context in jquery ajax success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var Box = function(){
    this.parm = {name:"rajakvk",year:2010};
    Box.prototype.jspCall = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "some url",
            success: this.exeSuccess,
            error: this.exeError,
            complete: this.exeComplete
        });
    }
    this.exeSuccess = function(){
        alert(this.parm.name);
    }
}
```

I'm not getting Box object inside exeSuccess method. How to pass Box object inside exeSuccess method?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use the [`context` option](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        context: this,
        type: "post",
        url: "some url",
        success: this.exeSuccess,
        error: this.exeError,
        complete: this.exeComplete
    });
```

The context option determines what context the callback is called with...so it determines what `this` refers to inside that function.

Comment: Extremely sorry. Over sighted jQuery documentation. It is clearly mentioned here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Maybe clearly mentioned, but not so clear as to how to use it. Nick's example is very helpful. This post goes into even more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097191/ajax-context-option