# $.ajax context option

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

Episode 11 of the [yayQuery](http://yayquery.com/) podcast mentions the [$.ajax context option](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).
How would I use this option in the success callback?
What I'm currently doing is passing my input parameters back to the success callback so that I can animate the id that was called after success/error.
If I use the context option, then perhaps I don't have to pass the parameters back from the called routine.

In this example, I pass STATEID back to the success field so that the state is removed from the DOM once it's been deleted from the database:

```
$('td.delete').click(function() {
  var confirm = window.confirm('Are you sure?');
  if (confirm) {
    var StateID = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'Remote/State.cfc',
      data: {
        method: 'Delete',
        'StateID': StateID
      },
      success: function(result) {
        if (result.MSG == '') {
          $('#' + result.STATEID).remove();
        } else {
          $('#msg').text(result.MSG).addClass('err');;
        };
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 125, accepted):

All the `context` does is it sets the value of `this` in the callbacks.

So if you're in an event handler, and you want `this` in the callbacks to be the element that received the event, you'd do:

```
context:this,
success:function() {
    // "this" is whatever the value was where this ajax call was made
}
```

If you wanted it to be some other type, just set that, and `this` will refer to that:

```
context:{some:'value'},
success:function() {
    // "this" the object you passed
    alert( this.some ); // "value"
}
```

---

In the code you added to the question, you could use `StateID`, but you wouldn't really need to since you already have access to that variable.

```
var StateID = $(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
$.ajax({
    url: 'Remote/State.cfc'
    ,data: {
        method:'Delete'
        ,'StateID':StateID
    }
    ,context: StateID
    ,success: function(result){

        alert(this);     // the value of StateID
        alert(StateID);  // same as above

        if (result.MSG == '') {
            $('#' + result.STATEID).remove();
        } else {
            $('#msg').text(result.MSG).addClass('err');;
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh, ok.  Thanks!  I'm still figuring out variable scope I suppose.

Comment: @cf_PhillipSenn: You're welcome. Yeah, it can be tricky. Probably the most common use of `context:` is the first solution where you want to retain the same value of `this` inside the callbacks as it was outside.

Comment: @user113716 So I have the option of putting one of these two in my ajax call:
`context:{parent_group:parent_group, container: container}`
`context:this`
And then I am doing `console.log(this.parent_group)`, shouldn't both of these work? Only the first one is working now.

Comment: Just in case anyone encounters this issue like I did. If you assign an arrow function (`() => {}`) to the `success` option, the `context` won't work (without error). You need to use the `function` keyword.

Answer (score 11):

If you set the context option, then `this` in success will be whatever you set as the value for `context`.  So if you pass an object literal containing your input parameter names and values as the context, then in success you could use `this.param1` to get the value of your first input parameter.

See the [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) docs for more.