# Refreshing an HTML page

Tags: jquery, python, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I refresh a page with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery)

How can I possibly trigger a reload of a page using either something in Django views.py or with Jquery? Basically, I want the page to automatically reload the same way when you click on the URL bar of a web browser and press enter does.

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: location.reload();//jquery, on some click/hover ...

Comment: @nithinreddy don't copy my accepted answer....
:P

Comment: window.location.reload()   or   window.location.reload( false )

Answer (score 18):

In javascript you can refresh the page as:

```
window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 4):

Don't go overboard with automatic full page refreshes; they're expensive. Consider performing AJAX calls at a reasonable interval to refresh just the information you need.