# How refresh the page in post method

Tags: php, ajax, post, get, fat-free-framework

I use fat free PHP framework.

PHP:

```
 F3::route('POST /vote', function(){
            global $twig;
            if(isset($_GET['studentKey'])){
                $studentKey = $_GET['studentKey'];
                //выборка id студента
                $SELECT_student_Id = "SELECT id FROM identification WHERE studentKey = '$studentKey'";
                DB::sql($SELECT_student_Id);
                $studentId = F3::get('DB->result');
                //выборка id преподавателя
                $SELECT_teacher_Id = "SELECT idPrep FROM kbinding WHERE idStudent =". $studentId[0]['id'];
                DB::sql($SELECT_teacher_Id);
                $teacherId = F3::get('DB->result');

                echo $twig->render('vote.html', array('ids' => $studentId[0]['id'],
                         'teacherId' => $teacherId[0]['idPrep']));
            }else{

                echo $twig->render('404.html', array('error' => 'Ошибка'));
            }
        });
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('#sendData').click(function(){
        $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "engine.php", data: some_data, 
            success:function(){
                ***location.reload();***
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error");
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

And I cant refresh the page, because it is a post method. How can I use Post method and refresh this page without problems??

Comment: If you want to refresh after POST, don't use AJAX, use SUBMIT.

Comment: You certainly can refresh a page with JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5404839/328193

Comment: I am exactly do it! In my java script file I have location.reload(); but I have an error Method Not Allowed GET request is not allowed for the URL /vote. This is a problem... how refresh the page. F3::route('POST /vote', functio... this page creates via post method as you see.. if it will be a get method, it will work

Comment: You have to add a GET route for /vote which displays the same content like the POST route after a successfull submit.

Comment: Thank you!) I have already done it!) I just forget to close a question!:)

Answer (score 0):

My solution is next:

1. Create form, add method 'post'
2. Create temp page, which receives values from form.

   2.1 Store this value in session

   2.2 After this, redirect to another page

Answer (score 0):

And you can use the reroute() method for the redirection.