# Prevent caching of HTML page

Tags: html, caching

I have a HTML page. The problem is that I do not want to have the users to refresh the page each time I put on new content.

I have the following code in order to make sure that the page is not cached:

```
     <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
     <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
     <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

The problem is, I still need to do a refresh on the page in order to get the most current content to show up. Am I doing something wrong? Should I be using some other tags?

Comment: will this really work? I would say, use php

Comment: @RyandeVries — Since the question says it *doesn't* work…

Comment: I ment by it that in my opinion this will never work, but I ain't sure though!

Comment: Do you mean you want content to auto-update while the user is watching a page, like a live stream? Or the next time a user visits your page, they seem to be displaying cached content?

Comment: I noticed history back as no effect, and a reload of the page is not automatic. Is there a way to get it to automatically reload?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The values you have there are OK, but [`meta http-equiv` is highly unreliable](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#META). You should be using real HTTP headers (the specifics of how you do this will depend on your server, e.g. [for Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html)).

Answer (score 34):

The Codesnippet you showed makes the browser load the website **everytime it accesses** it, which is useful if you perform frequent updates, but still have a static page.

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
```

In case you want it to perform **live updates**, like it does for example in a (g)mail account, you need to make it refresh (parts of the page) itself. Use Javascript in this case, like it is shown [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery?lq=1) or an ajax call.

```
$('#something').click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

Comment: Garrin, I have an HTML page and yes, I make frequent updates. As such shouldn't <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/> work? It seems like I still need to do a refresh

Comment: I still not surely know what you need/want to do. If you really need **live updates** while the user is still watching your page, you have to go for the Javascript/Ajax solution. But if you want the user to have the latest version of the website **everytime he visits it**, like if you update your website daily, your solution is good enough.

Comment: The reason is we are making updates to the html page which is a static page. We make these every 2 days. I like the user to see the latest version of it instead of clicking on refresh.

Comment: I read a bit about it and according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers) your snippet seems to be complete. I'm sorry if I couldn't help in this case.

Comment: Does this work for HTML5 web pages?

Comment: Does this work for the HTML files itself only, or also all referenced sources? Also, does this work for HTML5 too?

Comment: @Plantface Yes, HTML file only. All referenced sources would each need to return similar HTTP response headers. Each referenced source is a separate HTTP request. Any version of HTML. But this is really an HTTP protocol thing, rather than HTML.