# New version of web tool deployed -- Some users need to clear cache to retrieve clean new version

Tags: html, caching, web, browser-cache

We have a web tool that is going through a process of frequent updates.  Some of our users experience weird activity with new versions as their browser uses a combination of cached files from the previous version as well as files from the new version.  How can we ensure users get all the new updated files when they visit the page when a new version is on the server?

Comment: Found the solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716695/prevent-caching-of-html-page

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before. I found the easiest way to resolve it and still have the benefits of caching was to version the filenames (e.g. myscript.0.1.js). Either all of them if its not too many or at least the ones that changes regularly.