# How can a website developer make all users see the latest version?

Tags: browser-cache, web-development-server

I develop a simple web app with some CSS and Javascript. I often make changes or fix bugs, but my users do not see the fixes since their browser keeps the old version in the cache. I tell them to click Ctrl+R, and it mostly works in Firefox, but it does not work in Chrome. There is a way to force a hard refresh in Chrome (see https://superuser.com/q/220179/89652 ), but it is more complicated.

Can I, as a web developer, guarantee that my users always see the latest version, without having to tell them what to do?

Comment: Search "cache busting".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30764510/website-html-doesnt-update-for-users-because-of-cache