# How to refresh a location w. javascript when the location has a target?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is similar to, but not the same as [How can I refresh a page with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery):

I bring up a modal form that collects some stuff from the user and passes it off to the server via a `$.ajax()` call.  The server sends back a path that should become the new `window.location` of the browser. So the ajax call wants to be something like:

```
$.ajax({
   // stuff

   success: function (destination) {
      // other stuff
      window.location = destination;
   }),

   // still more stuff
});
```

This works fine as long as `destination` is a pure path, like `/some_path` *and* if the browser is not currently on that page.  However, if the path *is* the page that I'm currently on and also includes a target -- `/some_path#some_target`, I lose: the browser simply repositions the page at the specified target, but does not hit the server for a fresh view of the page, which I need (since the server has done some stuff during the ajax call).

So, maybe I just add a `location.reload()` after the `window.location` call?  That would work when the code is running on the page to which it's being returned, I think.  But if I'm on another page, I get hit by a race condition, where the reload is called before the browser has finished making the `window.location` change, and I get the old page reloaded, not the new destination.

Blurgh.  Is there any way around this?

Comment: Why are you using Ajax instead of a regular form post here?!

Comment: There are other things going on with the form that can require the jquery insertion of some stuff to the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to check if `window.location.pathname` (which is the path without `#` or `?`) is the same as `destination` within your success callback:

```
 success: function (destination) {
      // other stuff
      if (destination === window.location.pathname) {
          window.location.reload(); // reload if we are on the same page
      } else {
          window.location = destination; // otherwise, navigate to "other" page
      }
   }),
```

Comment: Thanks -- this ended up working (after a few tweaks specific to my situation)!

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.reload()` reloads the current page with POST data, while `window.location.href=window.location.href` does not include the POST data.