# Refresh on confirmation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me with refreshing the page after post success, instead of animate. I've tried window.opener.location.href, but it doesn't do any good. Thanks for your help!

```
$(function () {
    $(".delbutton").click(function () {
        //Save the link in a variable called element
        var element = $(this);
        //Find the id of the link that was clicked
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        //Built a url to send
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this item?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "delete",
                data: info,
                success: function () {

                }
            });
            $(this).parents(".record").animate({
                backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7"
            }, "fast")
                .animate({
                opacity: "hide"
            }, "slow"); //instead of this, I want page to refresh after confirmation
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: And did you try `window.location.reload()`

Comment: Just use `window.location.href = window.location.href` or `window.location.reload()`

Comment: What's the point of an AJAX request if you're refreshing the page anyway?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I refresh a page with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery)

Comment: @j08691 - was just typing that, why not just submit a form ?

Comment: @j08691 error reporting, validation, scroll position etc. I use it all the time.

Comment: Do you mean you want the refresh to happen *after* the animation finishes?

Comment: Add `window.location.reload()` inside the AJAX success function, and delete the animation code.

Comment: I've tried using the window.location.reload(). but it doesn't work. I think it's because of another plug in I'm using that is conflicting with my jquery.

Comment: @geedubb, I rather keep the animation but I'm using another plug-in that is preventing the animation to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was not a problem with the any third party plug-ins but I needed to include a `<tr class="record">`. It works after that!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just delete the element corresponding with the id on success?

Edited to add animation while removing the element:

```
  $(function () {
    $(".delbutton").click(function () {
        //Save the link in a variable called element
        var element = $(this);
        //Find the id of the link that was clicked
        var del_id = element.attr("id");
        //Built a url to send
        var info = 'id=' + del_id;
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this item?")) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "delete",
                data: info,
                success: function () {
                   // ADDITION HERE
                $('div[id='+ del_id +']').hide('slow', function(){ $('div[id='+ del_id +']').remove(); });

                }
            });

        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Mrk, I just tried that--the query went through, but page did not animate. I swear the x-editable plug-in doesn't play well with this script block...

Comment: Ok didn't you say you didn't want to animate it, you just wanted to remove the deleted link from the page?

Comment: Ok so its deleting the the element but not animating?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, change $(".delbutton").click(function () { TO $(".delbutton").click(function (e) { and insert the first line of that click function as e.stopPropagation();

Comment: Thats really rather odd, is the click function deleting it and not animating it? I do think its maybe a problem relating to x-editable, do you have this project online so I can take a look?

Comment: Mrk, no project online--I'm still testing it at the local level. At this point, I don't really care if it animates, I just want it to refresh!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are refreshing the page after an AJAX call, but if you really need to, this is how to do it. When the user confirms removal, send an AJAX request, and if successful, refresh the page.

```
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this item?")) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "delete",
        data: info,
        success: function () {
            window.location.reload();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @user2675057 try `window.location.href = window.location.href` instead of `window.location.reload()`.

Comment: I've tried both window.location.href = window.location.href and window.location.reload(), the page reloads, but the data did not go through the database. Any ideas?