# how to refresh page in php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i'm using ajax call on the php page(my.php) to pass JS variables and JS array to another php page(destiny.php). Now in destiny.php i do some DB operations.

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: "destiny.php",
    data: { b_Array : b_arr, b_value : b_val},
    success: function(data) {
        window.alert(data);
    }
```

But sometimes due to user inputted error (through Js variables or Js array), i have to show an alert (right now using above code `window.alert(data)` to show alert) But it doesn't refresh the page.

how can i refresh the page then? i tried header(). but still it doesn't work.

Comment: Header will not work in ajax call

Comment: try window.location.reload()

Comment: You have to do this in JS, right after alert. window.location.reload()

Comment: You can't do it with php! php is server side scripting language that can't interact with browser directly. Instead, you should use [javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17259514/2029693)

Comment: use window.location for redirection or window.reload for refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location)

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "POST",
    url: "destiny.php",
    data: { b_Array : b_arr, b_value : b_val},
    success: function(data) {
        window.location = "your_url";
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax(
  {        
    type: "POST",
    url: "destiny.php",
    data: { b_Array : b_arr, 
        b_value : b_val},
    success: function(data) {
      **window.location.reload();**
  }
```

but i think refreshing is not a good idea

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

This is the best way to reach what you want, although you also may check out this code bellow:

```
function auto_reload()
{

  var timer = window.location.reload();

   for (var i=0;i<timer.length;i++){

    setTimeout(timer, 1000);

    timer = false;


      }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

use

```
 window.location.href = document.URL;
```

or

```
   window.location.reload(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

itwill perform a refresh.

```
$.ajax(
      {        
        type: "POST",
        url: "destiny.php",
        data: { b_Array : b_arr, 
            b_value : b_val},
        success: function(data) {
        window.location.reload(true);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload);  Js Function

```
$.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
        url: "destiny.php",
        data: { b_Array : b_arr, 
            b_value : b_val},
        success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User either of this two option.

window.location.href = document.URL; 
OR
window.location.reload(true);

Write this at last in ajax response.
```

Thanks!