# How to update a modelForm in Django with Ajax

Tags: ajax, django

I would like to update a template with Ajax.

My problem is:

- I select a client in a list on the form and display only the corresponding data in an another list on the same page in a second list
- At this time, I can not update my template with protocols corresponding to the client
- In my views, I try to create a list with a queryset (it works)
  but I cannot update my template with the new list
- I retrieve the selected client but when I post with render_to_request
  it does not update the template
- Is there any possibility to do that and how can I update my list with the ajax part of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

(based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/21762215/5244995)

#### second_list.tmpl (template)

```html
{% for value in corresponding_data %}
    <li>{{ value }} (replace with your own templating)</li>
{% endfor %}
```

#### views.py

```
def update_second_list(request, ob_id):
    # (get the data here)
    return render('second_list.tmpl', {'corresponding_data': ...}
```

#### JS script on main page (uses jQuery)

```js
$.ajax({url:"", dataType:"text", success: function(html) {
    var newDoc = $.parseHTML(html, document, false); // false to prevent scripts from being parsed.
    var secondList = $(newDoc).filter(".secondList").add($(newDoc).find(".secondList"));
    $(".secondList").replaceWith(secondList); // only replace second list.
    // other processing
}});
```

Comment: Hello Thank you for your answer

Comment: Please could you explain me
the $(newdoc).filter    line

Comment: var secondList = $(newdoc).filter(".secondList").add($(newdoc)).find(".secondList));
TOKEN ILLEGAL 
Could you help me please

Comment: @user1987916 I accidentally introduced an error. See edit.