# jQuery: redirecting inside post not working

Tags: jquery, forms, redirect

i'm trying to redirect after a jquery post but redirecting simple doesn't work.
here's my code:

```
    post("/xForm.php", data, function(xml){
                var url = document.location.href;
                window.location.href = url; 
        }
     });
```

any ideas what could be wrong?
i'm using firefox, thanks

Comment: please be more specific, and post more code. and i do not know what do you want to achive also. you just want to refresh your page?

Comment: yes i simply want to refresh my page after the post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery

Comment: anyway, do you get some error in console?

Comment: um.. `location.reload()`

Comment: nope, no error. seems like it doesn't like the URL from document.location.href (maybe the http://..?) when manually setting the scriptname only, it works :/ .. location.reload(); will work for now, thanks!

Comment: is this in a form submit and you haven't prevented default submit? Also it should be `$.post`