# php page refresh not working after picture upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I refresh the page automatically after the user is done uploading profile picture? 
Well the picture gets updated once the user refreshes the page but I want to force refresh the page on its own.

I am uploading the file and updating my database like this:

```
$query="UPDATE users set image='".$username_db."_n.gif' where user_name='$username_db'";
mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

And after this I want a refresh code.

**I have tried several ways to do so:**

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>$('.display_picture_image').attr('src',    '".$src."?".time()."');<scipt>";
exit;
```

where **.display_picture_image** is the image tag where I want to display the picture.

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"
exit;
```

Then

```
header("Refresh:0");
exit();
```

Then

```
header("Location:".$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]);
exit();
```

Then

```
header("Location:page_name.php");
exit();
```

Then

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.reload();</script>";
```

But nothing is working. What am I doing wrong?

I have a page: index.php. It contains the form which is self referencing form.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])
    include 'upload.php';
```

Once the picture is submitted, the code from from

```
upload.php
```

is executed. The picture is then uploaded and then

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">$(window).on("load",function(){window.top.window.showcrop("'.$target_file.'","'.$username_db.'","'.$imageFileType.'");});</script>';
```

calls the **function showcrop.** in a js file which is linked in the header.

Then after the cropping area is selected and submitted this is executed:

```
function crop_photo() {
   var x_ = $('#x').val();
   var y_ = $('#y').val();
   var w_ = $('#w').val();
   var h_ = $('#h').val();
   var photo_url_ = $('#photo_url').val();
   var username_ = $('#username').val();
   var fileTypeImage_ = $('#imageFileType').val();

   // hide thecrop  popup
   $('#popup_crop').hide();

   // display the loading texte
  // crop photo with a php file using ajax call
  $.ajax({
     url: 'crop_photo.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: {x:x_, y:y_, w:w_, h:h_, photo_url:photo_url_, username:username_,     fileTypeImage:fileTypeImage_, targ_w:TARGET_W, targ_h:TARGET_H},
     success:function(data){
     // display the croped photo
   }
   });
 }

// updateCoords : updates hidden input values after every crop selection
function updateCoords(c) {
   $('#x').val(c.x);
   $('#y').val(c.y);
   $('#w').val(c.w);
   $('#h').val(c.h);
}
```

Then the crop.php is executed which uploads the cropped picture and updates the database. In the end, the refresh code is written but doesn't work.

Comment: You could do this client side when your database has been updated : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery

Comment: Post more code. Where do you run these refresh attempts after updating the picture?

Comment: To reach your goal you can use websockets.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider....i posted the code.

Comment: @jrenk...could u elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I figured out the answer on my own. In my **crop_photo.php** file I have,

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'crop_photo.php',
 type: 'POST',
 data: {x:x_, y:y_, w:w_, h:h_, photo_url:photo_url_, username:username_,       fileTypeImage:fileTypeImage_, targ_w:TARGET_W, targ_h:TARGET_H},
 success:function(data){
 // display the croped photo
 }
});
```

Well in the above code, i mentioned nothing within

```
success:function(data){
//display the cropped photo
}
```

Though that is where php is gonna echo stuffs. 
So I edited that as,

```
success:function(data){
//display the cropped photo
$('#image_div').html(data);
}
```

By this whatever I echoed in php was put inside the division with id **image_div**. 
Then I echoed

```
echo '<script>window.location='redirectbackurl.php'</script>';
```

and it redirected to **redirectbackurl.php** which redirected back to the previous link.
Code of my **redirectbackurl.php**

```
<?php
   header("Location:".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
   exit();
?>
```

Now i understand, i could simply use **location.reload()**, but due to form re submission issues, i did this.

Answer (score 2):

**SERVER SIDE :**

*Note :* Put below code after uploaded your file and updated your database :

```
  header("Refresh: 300;url='REDIRECTION URI'");
```

The browser will redirect after 300 seconds. It can be disabled in configuration of the browser though, but it's not commonly disabled.

**CLIENT SIDE :**

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: I tried doing this: `echo "<script type='text/javascript'>location.reload();</script>";` but it doesn't work. and header is not working either.

Comment: @bayblade567,Try this : echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location = 'YOUR URL'</script>"; Let me know if you still have any issues !

Comment: The echo statement is not getting executed at all because when I do inspect element, i see no such script and the page is not refreshing either. Do you think it is a logical error?

Comment: echo statement not executed mean you have errors in your page,Please enable error reporting & check errors on your page first !

Comment: well...am using wamp server..so i can click on php and it shows me php error log. over there...