# Redirect automatically to the login when the session is expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am using the .NET framework 4.5

I have set the `sessionState` to expire after 60 minutes. Every pages that require to be "logged" inherits from a class named `BasePage.cs`. On the `OnPreInit` event, this class verify the Session object and redirect to the login page when the session is expired.

Here is the configuration of the sessionState (web.config) :

```
<sessionState timeout="60"/>
```

Here is my verification in the class "BasePage.cs" :

```
protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["infosession"] == null)
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }

}
```

This verification is working great when the user is navigating trough the pages.

In some pages, I am using a WCF Service (Ajax-enabled) called from javascript. Between the time the pages will be generated and the time the WCF Service will be called, the session may expire. **Given that I should not assume that my Wcf Service's consumer will be a particular kind of software or have certain capabilities, as been a web browser, I can't do the verification there**.

So after some explanations, here the question :

Is it possible, when the session expire (after 60 mins), to redirect **automatically** to the login page ?

Comment: What type of authentication are you using?  Forms?

Comment: Yes, use `setTimeout` on client side to log off user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for client side solution - just set timer to expiration time (i.e. 1 hour) and [How can I refresh a page with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery):

```
 reloadTimer = setTimeout(60*60*1000, function() { location.reload();}
```

You may want to reset the timer if you get AJAX updates on the page that reset the session timeout.

Note that it no going to stop one from calling your WCF service directly, so it is not security measure but rather convenience.

Comment: Is there a way to do it server side, like when the session expire, throw an event to refresh the page ?

Comment: @Vinc웃 short version - no, longer - you'll need to redesign site to support connection back to client (i.e. raw web sockets or SignalR) and figure out what "session expires" means for non-in-memory state. Way too big for comment and possibly even for single SO question.

Comment: alright ! I will read on that ! Thank you a lot for your advice :)

Answer (score 1):

why not do something like the following instead

```
public static string Infosession 
{ 
    get 
    {
        object value = HttpContext.Current.Session["infosession"];
        return value == null ? "" : (string)value;
    }
    set 
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session["infosession"] = value;
    }
}
```

I would initialize the value in the OnSessionStart() in the Global.asax.cs file

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["infosession"] = string.Empty;
```

I would move this code 
    `protected override void OnPreInit`
to the `Page_Load() event`

another alternative

```
protected void Page_load(EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["infosession"] == string.Empty)
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}
```