# Jquery Countdown from x seconds to 0 in format hh:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have multiple html elements with the class "countdown":

```
<span data-seconds="95" class="countdown">00:01:35</span>
<span data-seconds="30" class="countdown">00:00:30</span>
```

and so on..
Now I want make a timer that countdown the value to 00:00:00, and then the page should be reload.
This I have in my script:

```
        // Countdown
        setInterval(function(){
            $(".countdown").each(function(){
                var seconds = $(this).data('seconds');
                if(seconds > 0) {
                    second = seconds - 1;
                    $(this).data('seconds', second)
                    $(this).html(second )
                }
            });
        }, 1000);
```

This works perfectly for seconds ... but can somebody help me to convert this into the hh:mm:ss format? 
in php there is the awesome function gmdate("H:i:s", $seconds) function.. I wonder there is some similar in JS?

And - how can I trigger the page reload if 
`$(this).data('seconds')` has 0?

Thanks for reply :)

Comment: and for what reason I get downvotes? I think I am describe my problem... and format this question in a readable format. I search here for my problem, but can't figure out a solution for my problem, so I ask here in a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your solution,, [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/murofuqesi/1/edit)

```
    // Countdown
    setInterval(function(){
        $(".countdown").each(function(){
            var seconds = $(this).data('seconds');
            if(seconds > 0) {
                second = seconds - 1;
                $(this).data('seconds', second)

                 var date = new Date(null);
                 date.setSeconds(second); 
                 $(this).html(date.toISOString().substr(11, 8))
            }
          else
            {
              $(this).html("Reload" )
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: works perfectly.. thanks!!! only the reload was not work. But I found this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery