# Refresh/Reload web page only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Check if the current URL contains '#' 
        if (document.URL.indexOf("#") == -1) {
            alert('dfjdkjfkdj');
            // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#".
            url = document.URL + "#";
            location = "#";

            //Reload the page
            location.reload(true);

        }
    });
</script>
```

Above code is not working.
What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I refresh a page with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery)

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Please provide the error message you are getting.

Comment: why setting location to # ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Page load the document.ready will execute and than it will apped the URL with # without any refresh/ reload. Here is the code for this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        //Check if the current URL contains '#' 
        if (document.URL.indexOf("#") == -1) {
            alert('dfjdkjfkdj');
            // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#".
            window.location.href = "#";

            //Reload the page
            window.location.href = window.location.href;

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `document.URL` doesn't change the url in the browser address bar. Use `location.href` instead:

```
location.href = location.href + '#';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this. This code should work fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //Check if the current URL contains '#' 
        if (document.URL.indexOf("#") == -1) {
            alert('dfjdkjfkdj');
            // Set the URL to whatever it was plus "#".
            window.location.href = window.location.href + "#";

            //Reload the page
            window.location.reload(true);

        }
    });
</script>
```