# Refresh page on tab click bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I create tabs to play videos, and need to refresh page while some one click on other tab to play other video. I attached script to remain on same page and reload page but reload not pause the video but reload shortly not clearly.

Not whole page refresh on tab click??

**HTML Part:**

```
<div id="tabs-list">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#t1" data-toggle="tab">Live 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t2" data-toggle="tab">Live 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t3" data-toggle="tab">Live 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#t4" data-toggle="tab">Live 4</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="t1" class="tab-pane fade in active"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'live1', true); ?></div>
        <div id="t2" class="tab-pane fade"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'live2', true); ?></div>
        <div id="t3" class="tab-pane fade"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'live3', true); ?></div>
        <div id="t4" class="tab-pane fade"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'live4', true); ?></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tabs-list').click(function () {
            location.reload();
        });
    });

    $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
    $("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
        var id = $(e.target).attr("href").substr(1);
        window.location.hash = id;
    });
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    $('#myTab a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show');

</script>
```

Comment: Could you please revise your description of the question? My understanding is - the page isn't refreshing, and the video on the first tab is still playing when a new tab is clicked... is this correct?

Comment: page is refresh but to short.. so that video still playing

Comment: need to refresh as we manually refresh in browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `location.reload(true)` overload which makes it not to be loaded from the cache.

The `true` parameter makes it not to be read from cache. 
You can reload the page with the help of anyone of these function, they should work.

1. location.reload()
2. history.go(0)
3. location.href = location.href
4. location.href = location.pathname
5. location.replace(location.pathname)
6. location.reload(false)

[for Reference from the other SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery)