# On first radio button click refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 3 radio buttons. I want to refresh my page on every click of 1st radio button (ie sel_address).Whenever the user clicks on selected address the page should refresh.I don't want the page to refresh on click of other 2 radio buttons.How can i achieve this ?

```
<label class="option sel_address">
        <input type="radio" value="sel_address" name="delivery_option" checked="checked" id="sel_address">
</label>
<strong>selected address</strong>

<label class="option your_school">
    <input type="radio" value="your_school" name="delivery_option" id="your_school">
</label>
<strong>school</strong>

<label class="option rhs_showroom">
    <input type="radio" value="showroom" name="delivery_option" id="showroom">
</label>
<strong>Showroom</strong>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $("input[name='delivery_option']").click(function() {
        .
        .
        var delivery_value = $(this).val();
        if(delivery_value == "your_school" || delivery_value == "showroom"){
            //some code 
        }else{
            ..
        }
    }
```

Comment: have a look into `:first` selector: https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

include below script just before the end of "body" tag.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#sel_address").click(function(){
    window.location = "";
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`eq(0)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select only the first element:

```js
$("input[name='delivery_option']").eq(0).click(function() {
  console.log('First was clicked');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="option sel_address">
  <input type="radio" value="sel_address" name="delivery_option" id="sel_address">
</label>
<strong>selected address</strong>

<label class="option your_school">
  <input type="radio" value="your_school" name="delivery_option" id="your_school">
</label>
<strong>school</strong>

<label class="option rhs_showroom">
  <input type="radio" value="showroom" name="delivery_option" id="showroom">
</label>
<strong>Showroom</strong>
```

Or the [`:first` pseudo class selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/):

```
$("input[name='delivery_option']:first").click(function() {
  console.log('First was clicked');
});
```

Comment: I think the ID is better, though arguably this is a moot accurate answer to the asked question.  Elements which are currently first, tend to be reordered later.

Comment: Well, the question was "click on the first" and not "click on a specific one" :) I'm not sure what will be the order in the future...

Comment: @DanFarrell, a vote will be appreciated here :) thanks!

Comment: Too late, sorry.  I went with the answer I feel is a better approach, and it's locked now anyway.

Comment: Not sure what is locked. Can you explain? (You can vote-up two answers, you know :) )

Comment: Learn something new sometimes just answering questions :).

Answer (score 0):

As [BeNdErR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1054151/benderr) and [Dekel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5037551/dekel) suggested, use the [`:first` pseudo-selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) to select the first radio button only.

As to reloading the page, use [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload), as suggested on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery).

```js
$("input[type='radio']:first").click(function() {
  location.reload();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="option sel_address">
  <input type="radio" value="sel_address" name="delivery_option" checked="checked" id="sel_address">
</label>
<strong>selected address</strong>

<label class="option your_school">
  <input type="radio" value="your_school" name="delivery_option" id="your_school">
</label>
<strong>school</strong>

<label class="option rhs_showroom">
  <input type="radio" value="showroom" name="delivery_option" id="showroom">
</label>
<strong>Showroom</strong>
```