# How to launch a new event: “reload page” when a class changes (disappears)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need refresh (reload) page when a particular class is not present (disappears). This class changed because another previous jQuery event (removeClass).

HTML initial (example):

```
<div class="class1 class2">
</div>
```

and after a event:

```
<div class="class1">
</div>
```

**when "class2" is not present I need launch the script to refresh page.**

Thanks (and sorry for my bad english).

Comment: why can't you refresh, when you are removing the class?

Comment: Dupe of [jQuery bind event to class change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed) plus [jQuery reload page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery)

Comment: do you control when you remove the class?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - Fire event if CSS class changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1950038/jquery-fire-event-if-css-class-changed)

Comment: You could use `MutationObserver`. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver out.

Comment: @Kuru because the class is removing after upload a image is finished, but the change no apply until page refresh (I would like it to be done automatically)

Comment: @Mohamed-Ted no, I'm not in control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MutationObserver`. I wrote an example here :

http://jsbin.com/vahixehema/edit?html,js,output

```
var target = document.getElementById('foo');

var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    if (mutation.attributeName === "class") {
      // the class of the target node changed
      if(!target.className.match(/\bbar\b/)){
        // bar is now not present
        alert("class 'bar' was removed");
        observer.disconnect();
        // reload the page here.
      }
    }
  });
});

observer.observe(target, { attributes: true });

// remove class after 3 seconds
window.setInterval(function(){
   target.classList.remove("bar");
}, 3000);
```

The basic idea is to listen for when the `class` attribute of your target node changes, and then when it does, check if the class you care about has been removed.

If you're using `jQuery` anyway, you could probably use `!$.hasClass('bar')` or something like that instead to check if the class has been removed.

Comment: That's right, but the class in observation first does not exist, then it appears (when loading a file) and after an event (the load ends) this disappear. When it’s not present again, it’s when I need to launch refresh order… With this code the command of reload is released continuously since the class does not yet exist at a start… How do I correct it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you ran the code? That's not the behavior I see. If I start with the node not having the class, then add it, and then later remove it, the refresh only happens when it is removed. See this : http://jsbin.com/winiyezivo/edit?html,js,output where I add `bar` after 3 seconds and remove it after 5.

Comment: Ummm ... true ... maybe some conflict with other scripts is preventing it from working as your demo. I look at it more closely. Thanks!