# jquery onclick append to class to force reload

Tags: jquery

If I have the following `<li>` menu item how could I make it so that on page load it appends a onclick reload function?

My issue is that the page is not updating when clicked and I have to force refresh the page to show the data.  If I can get it to force reload on click it would be great

**Example:**

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-625 current-cat active">
    <a href="http://domain.co.nz/product-category/brands/" data-id="625" class="lt-filter-by-cat lt-active">
       Brands
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery

Comment: @ChooHwan I have seen that however I want to refresh the link when clicked.  I have tried that and it just refreshs the current page

Comment: Do you want to replace the attribute href?

Comment: you want to reload whole page or reload some part with ajax?

Comment: the question is not clear to me. any of you guys think that the question is not clear? i'm tempted to say that <li onclick="location.reload()">hit me</li> is the answer