# need to refresh login page once user enter wrong details

Tags: jquery

i am trying to get my login page to refresh once a user enters the wrong account details. my problem is the page doesnt refesh once submitted the old details are not removed. how can i clear the page so the user can try again adding there account details

```
function signOut(email, password) {

   auth.signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
   }).catch(function(error) {
     // An error happened.
   });
};
```

Comment: The code provided is very less. Please provide us `signIn()` function code so that we can see how you come to know that given credentials are wrong. Then we can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I refresh a page with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery)

Comment: Call window.location.reload(), when you want to reload

Comment: in your error handler you can do something like `$("#login input").val("")`

Comment: i just added my main javascript for signin to the my first comment

Comment: inside `error` handler do `window.location.reload();` and check

Comment: i tried $("#login input").val("") this doesnt refresh the login page once the user  has made error on there details

Comment: i also tried $(document).ready(function(){
    $('login').each(function() {
        this.reset()
    });
});

Answer (score 0):

In signIn() function, when user will enter wrong details then it will come in error function at that time just refresh your page like this-

```
function signIn() {
        var email = $('#username').val();
        var password = $('#Password').val();

        initFirebase()
    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(
        function(user) {
            console.log(user)
            loginUsrEmail = user.email
            console.log(user.email)
            getData(loginUsrEmail)
        },
        function(error) {
            location.reload();        
        });

      };
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: your welcome... and please accept my answer if it satisfied you.

Comment: sorry to ask you before i was getting the message your email is wrong. and now i dont get the alerts only referesh the page. how can i get the alert messages.  thank you for helping

Comment: put your alert message code before refresh code. it will give you alert and then it will refresh your page.

Comment: like this -        function(error) {    console.log(error)
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        alert("" + errorMessage);
            location.reload();        
        });