# WebView Blank Screen on JavaScript Redirect (version 22)

Tags: android, webview

I have an Android app that uses WebView to access my website (https://m.readster.com)
The issues is that my website uses a "location.reload(); " function in JavaScript when opening the app.

This works wonders on Android 26 and 27, but I have a Huawei with Android 22 that after the redirect, only shows a white page. If I remove the redirect script, it will display the page normally.

Is there any way to make it display the page after the Reload command?

**EDIT**
I was calling

```
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
```

I should have been calling

```
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
```

Comment: I think u can get an idea from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/49116011/8111997

Comment: Thank you, but it did not work. It also does the same thing if I do the redirect from php.

Comment: Just found that navigating to any other page does not work either. White screen except for the initial page.