# How to refresh jsp page with ajax after a DB change

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have many clients that connect to a webservice. 
Everytime a client perform an action on the DB I want that all client can see the modify, by an updating of the jsp page that show the content of the DB.
How can I do this in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use websocket to refresh and renew page.
use this link what to use websocket:
[Jsp+tomcat7.047+html5 simple demo based on websocket](https://www.programering.com/a/MDO4cDMwATE.html)

Answer (score -1):

It is impossible by simply using ajax because the client (browser) don't know wwhen data is updated, and in client / server model, server can't send request to client to tell him.

Instead you should take a look at **websockets**. For example here :
http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0360__JSP/CreatingClientServerApplications.htm

Otherwise, you could simply refresh your web page by sending ajax requests periodically. If you are new to javascript, I recommand using jquery. **The way to do it depends on your needs.**

- If you prefer to reload the whole page, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5404869/5970908.
- To reload a portion of the page, you need to query a template, to get the refreshed html. Then insert it somewhere in the DOM. In this case, refer to the following topic
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9436594/5970908

Comment: "Otherwise, you could simply refresh your web page by sending ajax requests periodically."

How can I do this?