# How to pass data comming from database to templates dynamically (at run time /real time )

Tags: django, django-models, dynamic, django-templates

i have create one Django app in which i want to pass data to html template which is comming from my database (table's  last entered user name ) and show it html page but user name can automatically change to new one without refreshing page

Comment: What's the use case? Does the user logout or switch profiles?

Comment: You could trigger an ajax call by the JS window.setTimeout function.

Comment: @Reez0 no no i create a html page where visitor enter there name and this name display on another page , actually i am learning Django now

Comment: @ger.s.brett but how i render data when i already extract it from database and then send to template

Answer (score 0):

I would query the latest username using something like this:

```
username = Username.objects.order_by('-created_at').first()
```

Then you can dynamically update the page by reloading it using jQuery. More info on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery)

Comment: Take a look at these jQuery examples - [https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/](https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/)