# Celery worker exit with shell

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

i use Celery with Django on a Debian server.
I connect to the server with putty via ssh and start the celery worker with the following command

```
celery -A django-project worker
```

Now i would like to close putty but than the celery worker exit apparently.
Why and what can i do to always run the celery worker?

Comment: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/daemonizing.html

Comment: You can also use Supervisor to start celery. It will also restart processes. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404839/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-with-jquery).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start celery [daemonized](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/daemonizing.html):

```
celery multi start worker1 -A django-project
```