# jQuery ajax mixed html/js <script> avoid losing context when <script> opens

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing the following situation.
I use ajax to communicate with the backend which responds with mixed html/js code. I use the html() function to load my content in a div - i.e. `$("#mydiv").html(ajaxResponse);`

However, the js code embedded in `<script>` tags in the `ajaxResponse` runs in global (window) context and not my predefined one.

Is there any way to change the context of execution in this situation?

code looks like the following

index.html:

```
<div id="mydiv"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: '/myAjaxResponse.html',
      context: $(this),
      success: function(resp) { $("#mydiv").html(resp); }
   });
});
</script>
```

myAjaxResponse.html:

```
<!-- Some html... really just anything :) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log($(this));   // $(this) points to window object :(
</script>
```

Comment: What would be your desired context? `#mydiv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit:*** Uh, wait, I just realized I misunderstood your question …

Since You're inserting into the DOM, all JS loaded via XHR is in the `window` scope automatically – and afaik, there's no proper way around that. All the `context` option of `$.ajax()` does, is setting the value of `this` *in the callback function*.

(Also, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097214/961510) which explains things better than I ever could).

One possible, although very very quirky way around the problem would be to set a global variable that you can call later (something along these lines):

```
var context;

$(function(){
   context = $('whatever');
   $.ajax({
      url: '/myAjaxResponse.html',
      success: function(resp) { $("#mydiv").html(resp); }
   });
});
```

myAjaxResponse.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $this = context;
    console.log($this);   // $this points to whatever you set context to before XHR
</script>
```

---

To make a long story short: `$(this)`, in the context of your `$.ajax()` call, does indeed point to `window`.

You could/should either go with

```
$(function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: '/myAjaxResponse.html',
      context: $('#mydiv'),
      success: function(resp) { $("#mydiv").html(resp); }
   });
});
```

or (somewhat quirkily) with

```
$(function(){
   $('#mydiv').each(function(){
       $.ajax({
          url: '/myAjaxResponse.html',
          context: $(this),
          success: function(resp) { $("#mydiv").html(resp); }
       });
   })
});
```

… where `this` points to the element being iterated over by `$.each()`.

Comment: "all JS loaded via XHR is in the window scope automatically" Precisely.

Comment: ah, my bad (typo), yes, in the $.ajax({context: $("#mydiv)... }) is what I meant :)
So, the only way is by global vars right? :(
So, if build some uid, attach it to the #mydiv data and "select" based on that uid it should work right?
(Will also read the provided link - thanks :)