# JQuery getScript with livequery - asynchronous execution throwing off my results

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, livequery, getscript

We had a "utility" js function that was included in several js files in our site, so to reduce code repetition we moved it to a utilities file and modified all the js files to load it before using it with `getScript`. This worked in most cases, but with one piece of code that uses livequery I'm getting errors.

The code that I am using successfully wherever we need to use the new function:

```
$.getScript("js/utilities.js", function(){
   ... use parseQueryString function ....
});
```

**Code before:**

```
$('.preview')
    .livequery(function(){
            $(this).attr('rel','myPage.cfm?' + parseQueryString($(this).attr('rel')));
        });
```

Basically, whenever an element with a class of "preview" shows up on the scene, we want to parse the rel attribute and replace it with the newly parsed string.

**Code after:**

```
$('.preview')
    .livequery(function(){
            var preview = $(this);
            // load utilities.js so that we can access the parseQueryString function
            $.getScript("js/utilities.js", function(){
                preview.attr('rel','myPage.cfm?' + parseQueryString(preview.attr('rel')));
            });
        })
```

The problem is, this seems to be continuing to the next iteration of the `$('.preview').livequery` loop before executing the callback of the `getScript` call. So the `preview` variable gets reset before we can replace its rel attribute with the appropriate value. How can I get this to execute correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A work-around I just came up with that seems to be working... Put the getScript call around the livequery loop:

```
 // load utilities.js so that we can access the parseQueryString function
$.getScript("js/utilities.js", function(){
    $('.preview')
        .livequery(function(){
            $(this).attr('rel','myPage.cfm?' + parseQueryString($(this).attr('rel')));
        })
});
```

Comment: This looks somewhat better, however I'm not sure your liveQuery will function properly if you dynamically add more matching elements as this one is enclosed in the callback and once it finishes looping...

Answer (score 0):

I think you named the problem in your title :) 'asynchronous' is exactly the cause - loading the utility is on and since the request will be made and execution will move on meanwhile..entering yet another livequery callback if more matches are available. Frankly I think it's really bad idea to put a script loading inside a function that will be looped multiple times - it's just somewhat pointless. I see no reason not to just include it like a normal script:

```
<script src="js/utilities.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I think this is the simplest and most reasonable solution. 
However, if you really can't use this for some reason, either ensure local copy of the variable for the callback via context (see [$.ajax context option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097191/ajax-context-option/5097214#5097214) since getScript is a $.ajax shortcut it should have it too) or try synchronous ajax...the last one is an option, but please don't really try it in this case :)

Comment: I don't think you can include the script in the js file using your code, can you?

Comment: Why not? It's a script file available on the server you request with Ajax multiple times. Why not let the browser get it with the rest of the page content a single time?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file

Comment: It's a slightly different direction to what i was thinking, but I am looking at it and it is there:
"2 - Add a script tag with the script URL in the HTML." in the answer
Your js code needs to be added to the page one way or another, it's more than OK to include the utility it uses before it, just like you invclude jQuery in advance in order to make use of it.