# Return from jQuery Ajax Method

Tags: jquery

I have a button named searchReportButton. On this button click, I need to check session value from server using a ajax web method "Error.aspx/CheckSessionExpiry".This is done in checkSession javascript function. The checkSession is not returning anything now - instead it is handling the required operation based on the result (redirecting to error page).

1. I need to return the result of ajax web method to the Main Caller.  How can we do this return?
2. Do I need to move the remaining code (from Main Caller) into sucsess callback?

**Main Caller**

```
searchReportButton.click(function () {

    checkSession();
    //Remainging Code

});
```

**Helper**

```
function checkSession() {

var win = 101;
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "Error.aspx/CheckSessionExpiry",
            data: '{"winNumber": "' + win + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: handleSessionResult

        }
        );
        }
```

**Result Helper**

```
  function handleSessionResult(result) {


    if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) 
    {
      result = result.d
    }

    if (result == "ACTIVE") 
    {
      window.location.href("Error.aspx");
      return false;
    }

   //alert(result);
```

}

REFERENCE:

1. [How can I get jQuery to perform a synchronous, rather than asynchronous, Ajax request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-re)
2. [$.ajax context option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097191/ajax-context-option/5097214#5097214)
3. [jQuery Ajax Callback does not get Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670564/jquery-ajax-callback-does-not-get-context)
4. [jQuery pass more parameters into callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/939032/jquery-pass-more-parameters-into-callback)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Variable doesn't get returned JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475269/variable-doesnt-get-returned-jquery)

Comment: Not a duplicate. This question has an extra part -- How to deal the `remaining code` part. It is answered also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. Or, to be more specific, you **should** not. Ajax request is `async` which means it does not block other JS operations while it's being proceeded (imagine 5s browser freeze if the server was responding slowly?).

Instead you can pass a `success` callback, which you already do. Then do anything you wanted in there.

So instead of:

```
checkSession();
//Remainging Code
```

you should move the remainging code inside the callback:

```
function handleSessionResult(result) {
    //... current code
    //Remaining code from the above
}
```

Comment: Will the remaining code in Main Caller be executed before it completes the ajax call?

Comment: Yes, because ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: Can sync:true in Ajax method help?

Comment: @Lijo, yes, but you should never use it. If you set async to false you are no longer doing AJAX - you are freezing the client browser. You are basically killing the whole purpose of AJAX which is meant to be asynchronous.

Comment: No, ajaxes are supposed to be async. If they weren't user's browser would freeze for as long as it took to execute the ajax.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov If `async = false` is not good, how can I ensure that remaining code will not execute before the ajax call is complete? Do you think what I am doing at present is the best possible solution?

Comment: @Lijo, very easy - you should put the remaining code inside the success callback -> there shouldn't be any code after the AJAX call that relies on the result of this call.