# jQuery Ajax Callback does not get Context

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML page as shown in  http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/zPAfF/6/ .  When “searchReportButton” button is clicked a javascript function “checkSession” is invoked. Inside the “checkSession” function there is a `jquery.ajax` call to a `web method` listed below. The web method is working fine and I am able to alert the result as “ACTIVE” in javascript success callback.

I have set the context as this.

```
 context: this,  //CONTEXT
```

I am expecting the following code to alert the “Loading…” text. The assumption is `this` will work in the `success callback` since the `context` is set. But it not showing the text.

```
if (result == "ACTIVE") 
{       
    var selectedTable = $(this).closest('.dateFilter').siblings('.sentDatesSection').find('.reportSentDatesDiv');

    alert($(selectedTable).text());

}
```

**QUESTION**

What need to be corrected in order to get the context in the callback?

*Web Method*

```
    [WebMethod(CacheDuration = 0)]
    public static string CheckSessionExpiry(string empID)
    {

        return "ACTIVE";
    }
```

[image]

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var searchReportButton = $('.searchReportButton');
    searchReportButton.click(function() {
        var selectedTable = $(this).closest('.dateFilter').siblings('.sentDatesSection').find('.reportSentDatesDiv');
        alert($(selectedTable).text());
        checkSession();
        return false;
    });
});

function checkSession() {
    var empID = 101;
    alert('Function Reached');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Error.aspx/CheckSessionExpiry",
        data: '{"empID": "' + empID + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        //CONTEXT
        success: handleSessionResult
    });
}

function handleSessionResult(result) {
    if (result.hasOwnProperty("d")) {
        result = result.d
    }
    if (result == "ACTIVE") {
        var selectedTable = $(this).closest('.dateFilter').siblings('.sentDatesSection').find('.reportSentDatesDiv');
        alert($(selectedTable).text());
    }
}​
```

**HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
<title>Report List </title>

</head>
<body>
<form>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="centralContainer">
            <div id="mainContainer">
                <div id="contentHolderDiv" class="contentHolderDiv">
                    <div id="searchContainer" class="searchContainer">
                        <div id="entryValues" class="repeaterContainer">
                            <div class="repeaterTableBorder">
                                <div class="repeaterRecord">
                                    <div class="repeaterIdentifier">
                                        <div class="reportTitle">
                                            Daily Financial Transaction:
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="viewLogTitle">
                                        <div class="viewLogText">
                                            View Report Log
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div id="reportLog" class="reportLog">
                                        <div class="dateFilter">
                                            <div class="filterElements">
                                                <div class="filterContents">
                                                    <input type="submit" name="ctl00$detailContentPlaceholder$repReports$ctl00$btnSubmit"
                                                        value="Get Reports" id="detailContentPlaceholder_repReports_btnSubmit_0" class="searchReportButton" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="sentDatesSection">
                                            <div class="reportSentDatesDiv">
                                                <p>
                                                    Loading...</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clear">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `this` as argument to the `checkSession` function:

```
checkSession(this);
```

and then:

```
function checkSession(context) {
    var empID = 101;
    alert('Function Reached');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Error.aspx/CheckSessionExpiry",
        data: JSON.stringify({ empID: empID }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        context: context,  //CONTEXT
        success: handleSessionResult

        }
    });
}
```

Also notice how I have fixed your `$.ajax` call to use the `JSON.stringify` method in order to ensure that the request is properly JSON formatted. **Never**, and I repeat, **absolutely never** use string concatenations (`+` operator) to build JSON. The `JSON.stringify` method is natively built into all modern browsers. And if you have to support some browser that comes from the [Mesozoic era](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesozoic) such as IE6 or something you could reference the [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) script to your page.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

```
checkSession.call(this);
```

Or, its sibling [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).