# Cannot remove element after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, phalcon

I have this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.remove',function(e){
        // e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).data('file');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/backup/delete',
            data:'fileName='+data,
            success: function(data){
                $(this).parents('tr').remove();
            }
        },'json');
    });
});
```

and document portion:

```
<tr>
                <td>adif20150331133844.adi</td>
                <td style="width: 2em"><span class="remove link" data-file="adif20150331133844.adi"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></td>
                <td style="width: 2em"><span class="restore link" data-file="adif20150331133844.adi"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat" aria-hidden="true"></span></span></td>
            </tr>
```

The task is to delete tr portion after file is removed. I cannot make it work. File is getting removed the respond is 200, OK but remove() doesnt work even if I replace success with complete in ajax. What could it be?

Comment: the `$(this)` will not work under success function of ajax you will have to store it into some variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click','.remove',function(e){
    // e.preventDefault();
    var oThis = $(this);
    var data = $(this).data('file');
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/backup/delete',
        data:'fileName='+data,
        success: function(data){
            oThis.parents('tr').remove();
        }
    },'json');
});
});
```

Answer (score 6):

The context of element is lost in ajax call, you can set the context to ajax using option `context`:

```
$.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/backup/delete',
        context:this,
        data:'fileName='+data,
        success: function(data){
            $(this).parents('tr').remove();
        }
    },'json');
```

**[Context option in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097214/1719752)**

Answer (score 1):

get **this** as one variable as and use it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.remove',function(e){
        // e.preventDefault();

var _this=$(this);  // assign this as one variable
        var data = _this.data('file');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/backup/delete',
            data:'fileName='+data,
            success: function(data){
                _this.parents('tr').remove();  // here this not .remove                 }
        },'json');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `$this` variable with `$(this)` and use it in your success handler of your Ajax call like so.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).on('click','.remove',function(e){
        var $this = $(this); // set it
        // e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).data('file');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/backup/delete',
            data:'fileName='+data,
            success: function(data){
                $this.parents('tr').remove(); // use it
            }
        },'json');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign some variable on click `datathis` use it in success function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.remove',function(e){
        // e.preventDefault();
       var datathis=$(this);  // assign this as one variable
        var data = _this.data('file');
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/backup/delete',
            data:'fileName='+data,
            success: function(data){
                datathis.parents('tr').remove();  
}
        },'json');
    });
```