# tr didn't remove in ajax request.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i m trying to remove tr from table using closest function.
this function is working properly out of the $.post request but when same script is used in post request its not working.
My Code is

```
$(".delete_cat").click(function() {
        var idd = $(this).val();

        $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>category/delete",
            {id:idd},
            function(data) {

                if (data === 1) {
                    var tr = $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");
                    tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
                        tr.remove();
                    });

                }
            }
            )

    })
```

Comment: `this` will be different when it is called from post `success` function .. see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33095435/2074346

Comment: what closest do ? i am just commenting to learn. @hamaad.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/closest/ @YoYo

Answer (score 0):

That is because context of element is lost in ajax call. you can use context option of ajax to set context of clicked `.delete-cart` element:

```
   $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>category/delete",
   {id:idd},
   context:this,
   function(data) {
     if (data === 1) {
         var tr = $(this).closest('tr').remove();
         tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");
         tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
         tr.remove();
     }
   });
```

**[Context option in ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5097214/1719752)**

Answer (score 0):

`this` is having different instance inside `post` `success` function

```js
$(".delete_cat").click(function() {
  var that = this
  var idd = $(that).val();

  $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>category/delete", {
      id: idd
    },
    function(data) {

      if (data === 1) {
        var tr = $(that).closest('tr').remove();
        tr.css("background-color", "#FF3700");
        tr.fadeOut(400, function() {
          tr.remove();
        });

      }
    }
  )

})
```

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` inside function is not refer to `.delete_cat`, but window instead, cache those :

```
$(".delete_cat").click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);  // <----here
   var idd = $this.val();

    $.post("<?php echo base_url() ?>category/delete",
        {id:idd},
        function(data) {
            if (data === 1) {
                var tr = $this.closest('tr').remove();
                tr.css("background-color","#FF3700");
                tr.fadeOut(400, function(){
                    tr.remove();
                });
            }
   });
});
```

Comment: `.delete_cat` is dynamic element?

Comment: <button type="button" class="delete_cat" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">Delete</button>

Comment: No i mean, is it table are created dynamically? And do you try to alert something on click handler?