# $(document).on() not working after ajax when using $(this)

Tags: jquery

I have currently have this code

```
$(document).on("click", ".element", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "ajax/ajax-submit.php",
        success:function(data){
            if(data == "success") {
                console.log("deleted upload");
                $(this).parents(".parent-element").remove();
            }
        },error: function(data){}
    });
});
```

and this is the HTML

```
<div class="parent-element">
     <div class="container">
          <button class="element">Remove Parent</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

that `$(this)` is not working after success of ajax.

What I want is to remove the parent of this `.element` that is `.parent-element`.

> **Note*: This `.element` is a appended element inside `.parent-element`.**

Comment: which JQuery library have you imported? Also check for syntax on the API page.

Comment: You need to either use a helper variable to set `this` to or use the context option on the ajax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097191/ajax-context-option

Comment: Use $('.element').parents(".parent-element").remove(); instead of $(this).parents(".parent-element").remove();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 0):

Because `this` is now belongs to `success` method, add variable `oThis` and then use in `success` method to remove

```
$(document).on("click", ".element", function(e){
    var oThis = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: "ajax/ajax-submit.php",
        success:function(data){
            if(data == "success") {
                console.log("deleted upload");
                $(oThis).parents(".parent-element").remove();
            }
        },error: function(data){}
    });
});
```

Comment: does `oThis` stand for `original this`? :)

Comment: Its variable, for assigning `this` to `oThis` variable :)

Comment: @MaxBaldwin I go with `var that = this` :)

Comment: i always go for `var me = this`, it keeps me calm at night

Comment: Folks are enjoying :)