# Success part of a function does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two input with type text, and I wrote a function onkeyup when the user starts to write somthing I send my data to another page that is called "jsonpage.html".
but the success part of my code does not work.
I Think it cannot find the address of divs . but at first part it could find it. I don't have any idea that why it doesn't work in success part ?
if you omit part "$(this).closest(".main").find" fro success it works .but after i add these lines it does not .

here is my snippet :

```js
$('.country').each(function() {
$(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
        var element = $(this).val().length;
        if (e.which !== 0 &&
            !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.altKey
        ) {
            if (element > 2) {

                $(this).closest(".main").find(".mini-loading").css("display", "block")
                var val = $(this).val()
                val = val.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1).toLowerCase();
                $(this).val(val)
                $.ajax({
                    url: "jsonpage.html",
                    type: "get",
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    data: {
                        key: $(this).val()
                    },
                    success: function(result) {
                        $(this).closest(".main").find(".mini-loading").css("display", "none")
                        $(this).closest(".main").find(".co").empty().html(result)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="city1">
    <input type="text" value="" class="country" placeholder="First City" />
    <input value="" type="hidden" />
    <div class="mini-loading" style="display: none; ">
      LOADING
    </div>
    <div class="co"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="main">
  <div class="city2">
    <br/>
    <input type="text" value="" class="country" placeholder="Second City" />
    <input value="" type="hidden" />
    <div class="mini-loading" style="display: none; ">
      LOADING
    </div>
    <div class="co"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If `result` is on json format. You might want to format it before `.html()`

Comment: **json** page **.html**?

Comment: @Eddie if I write $(".mini-loading").css("display", "none")
                        $(".co").empty().html(result)  in success my code works well for both of them . but I want to run codes for each parts separately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is probably due to the scope of `this` in your success callback function that is not pointing anymore to your input but on the ajax call.

Try to store your value like this :

```
$(this).on('keyup', function(e) {
   // Store the initial value of this ---------------------------------
   var _this = this;

   var element = $(this).val().length;
    if (e.which !== 0 &&
        !e.ctrlKey && !e.metaKey && !e.altKey
    ) {
        if (element > 2) {

            $(this).closest(".main").find(".mini-loading").css("display", "block")
            var val = $(this).val()
            val = val.substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + val.substr(1).toLowerCase();
            $(this).val(val)
            $.ajax({
                url: "jsonpage.html",
                type: "get",
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: {
                    key: $(this).val()
                },
                success: function(result) {

                   // And use it here at least ----------------------
                    $(_this).closest(".main").find(".mini-loading").css("display", "none")
                    $(_this).closest(".main").find(".co").empty().html(result)
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
```

You can also use `$(e.target)` (event target element) instead of `this` to fetch back your input element

And finally, you may also use jquery context option. See [How to pass context in jquery ajax success callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3863536/how-to-pass-context-in-jquery-ajax-success-callback-function)